# Typescript How to express string concatenation in type system

Tags: typescript, types

I would like to make sure, that string contains other string, at transpile time:

```
type OneOrTwo = "one" | "two"
type StringContainingOneOrTwo = string
let str: StringContainingOneOrTwo = "123" + "one" // ok, contains OneOrTwo
let str2: StringContainingOneOrTwo = "123" + "onesss" // should fail, does not contain OneOrTwo
```

Comment: This is getting closer, with [microsoft/TypeScript#40336](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336), but the compiler still doesn't understand that the expression `"123"+"one"` has the type `"123one"`

Answer (score 1):

> Typescript How to express string concatenation in type system

You can't do that. Especially with *contains* e.g. your example

```
let str2: StringContainingOneOrTwo = "123" + "onesss" // should fail, does not contain OneOrTwo
```

Actually *does* contain `one` i.e. `123 + one + sss`. But even with *ends with* you can't encode that in the typescript type system.

Comment: Relevant GitHub issue: [Microsoft/TypeScript#6579](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579), suggestion to support regexp validated string literal types

Comment: Regex validation would still (probably) not validate concatenation `'a'+'b'`. Only `'ab'`.